# multilaguage site - web page translation

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, multilingual

Before I start I'd like to mention that I know that there is alot of answers about multilanguage functionality, I just didn't found the answer I 'd hope I found from my little search.

I have a page (e.g. about.php) where all the content is just html, having many heading tags, p tags, list-items etc etc. The content is 'static', meaning that it is NOT coming from the database and I'd like to apply translation on it by clicking a link (english or french).

I've followed some tutorials and examples and come up with something quite similar to [this](http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html) example, but what concerns me is about the content of the page. What I'm trying to say is this:
Suppose my page structure looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php"><?php echo $lang['HOME']; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="about.php"><?php echo $lang['ABOUT']; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=fre">french</a></li>
</ul>
<h1><?php echo $lang['HEADING']; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $lang['PARAGR']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $lang['ANOTHER_PAR']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The values of the nav menu could easily stored inside a $lang array and echo out the specific one each time, but is this also the best (or more efficient) way to do it and with the page content?? Do I have to put in the $lang all my headings and paragraphs and lists etc etc or this can be easily done with a better way? What if some paragraphs have too much text inside? etc

Hope that make sence.

P.S Iwas also thinking of making two different files, like about_eng.php and about_fre.php, where I have all the html content in english and in french respectively and with a simple if statement to check which language is selected each time and include the right file

Comment: I believe the first approach is better. In the second approach, you will need to keep up changes on both the files which calls for redundant effort. You should not be worrying about the text as php can handle it pretty neatly. hope this helps :)

Comment: I think in both cases any changes made will cost redundant effort, as and in the first one the changes must be done in both the english vresion and french. But is also and the fisrt approach best practise???

Comment: I translated my page using the Array method. It works fine. But there are other ways. Have you heard of Gettext? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext

Comment: In first approach what you will be doing is not called redundancy. The text , you will have to update as per language. With redundancy i mean, if you decide to change the html in future, you will have to do it across all pages. Also, using any language translators will not help as human language is contextual and mapping it exactly is still under development.

Comment: Ok so I guess I 'll have to keep on with the first one. Is there also some other approach to this which is more better/prefered? because still this looks like a little bit 'painfull'. 
@ Adam Brown: I've never used it, but I feel it does the same thing as google-translate, which i wasn't happy with the results i got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your language specific data in different php files declaring $lang array is a good way I think. That will avoid retyping all content with language, meaning less redundancy.
So I agree with Jaspal. For typing $lang['XXX'] you can convert the php into this easily(maybe a stupid solution but it will work):

```
function displayMyPage() {
global $lang;     // do not forget the other globals you need in the page...
$l = $lang;       // localize $lang as $l... 
?>  
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php"><?php echo $l['HOME']; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="about.php"><?php echo $l['ABOUT']; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=fre">french</a></li>
</ul>
<h1><?php echo $l['HEADING']; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $l['PARAGR']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $l['ANOTHER_PAR']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: if the task is type as few as possible symbols my translation looks like  <?= t('home'); ?>  =)  
I create a lang file for each language with associative array and 'home' is key, large text translations puts to database